# Hashicorp Vaultsharp permission denied error

Tags: asp.net-core, hashicorp-vault, vaultsharp

**Error**

> System.Exception: Vault configuration failed: One or more errors occurred. ({"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n"]}
>   )
>      at VaultConnection.VaultExtensions.AddVaultKeys.GetValutKeyValuePairs(IConfiguration buildConfig) in C:\Users\48013\Source\Repos\sample\Vault1\VaultConnection\VaultExtensions\AddVaultKeys.cs:line 67
>      at VaultConnection.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in

**Summary**

> Using AppRoleAuthMethodInfo method to read key-values from Hashicorp
>   Vault results me - permission denied error. A small snippet of code
>   mentioned below to describe the problem.

**Here is the Snippet of code  :**

```
IAuthMethodInfo authMethod = new AppRoleAuthMethodInfo(buildConfig["vault:roleid"], buildConfig["vault:secretid"]);

var VaultClientSettings = new VaultClientSettings(buildConfig["vault:address"], authMethod);

IVaultClient vaultClient = new VaultClient(VaultClientSettings);

 // Token Apis.
var callingTokenInfo = vaultClient.V1.Auth.Token.LookupSelfAsync().Result;

var vaultSecrets = vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V1
                        .ReadSecretAsync(buildConfig["vault:path"])
                        .Result.Data;

---> It throws error at this point and failed to execute the above line var vaultSecrets = vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V1.........
```

**DisplayJson(callingTokenInfo) Output**

> Output of this token is - 
>   {"request_id":"e5e71c03-6972-12ff-9e30-d42c8e2f188a","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":0,"data":{"accessor":"FuLTEKwYmJ2IGZyDwvCmJ1Vm","explicit_max_ttl":0,"renewable":true,"creation_time":1591617019,"creation_ttl":2764800,"orphan":true,"ttl":2764799,"type":"service","id":"s.6GJMAbWxQU82cm1K7ajcSgv5","policies":["default","sqlconnection"],"meta":{"role_name":"sqlconnectionrole"},"path":"auth/approle/login","display_name":"approle","num_uses":0,"entity_id":"811d33fe-e9e5-ac4e-3fbf-9809c0a85b3d","expire_time":"2020-07-10T17:20:19.2386078+05:30","identity_policies":null,"issue_time":"2020-06-08T17:20:19.2386078+05:30"},"wrap_info":null,"warnings":null,"auth":null}

**In addition to this, steps to create policy and to associate with a role**

```
1. vault secrets enable -path=devkv kv
2. vault kv put devkv/connection timeout=120 source=DATA
3. vault policy write sqlconnection sqlconnection.hcl
4. Output of the policy created: - vault policy read sqlconnection
```

> path "devkv/*" {
>     capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
>   }
>
> path "devkv/appId*" {
>     capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
>   }

```
5. vault auth enable approle
6.  vault write auth/approle/role/sqlconnectionrole policies=default,sqlconnection
7. vault read auth/approle/role/sqlconnectionrole/role-id
8. vault write -f auth/approle/role/sqlconnectionrole/secret-id

If I test this through a command line, I am able to access the keys
9. vault write auth/approle/login role_id="1a5aa9a5-9d79-5743-de-9dca0433dc77" secret_id="138ec92b-02c8-610d-109b-3f325e29be"
```

**Output of the commands executed for Step -9**

```
Received a token from this command. Login with this token to check whether or not keys associated with sqlconnection role can be read and I was successfully able to read the value.
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> vault write auth/approle/login role_id="1a5aa9a5-9d79-5743-3cde-9dca0433dc77" secret_id="138ec92b-02c8-610d-109b-3f325e29bef0"
> Key                     Value
> ---                     -----
> token                   s.g5NfR7DJLSD9hp1amXCvp92I
> token_accessor          u5raQKxARuAjluywS1SatFuy
> token_duration          768h
> token_renewable         true
> token_policies          ["default" "sqlconnection"]
> identity_policies       []
> policies                ["default" "sqlconnection"]
> token_meta_role_name    sqlconnectionrole
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> vault login s.g5NfR7DJLSD9hp1amXCvp92I
> WARNING! The VAULT_TOKEN environment variable is set! This takes precedence
> over the value set by this command. To use the value set by this command,
> unset the VAULT_TOKEN environment variable or set it to the token displayed
> below.
> 
> Success! You are now authenticated. The token information displayed below
> is already stored in the token helper. You do NOT need to run "vault login"
> again. Future Vault requests will automatically use this token.
> 
> Key                     Value
> ---                     -----
> token                   s.g5NfR7DJLSD9hp1amXCvp92I
> token_accessor          u5raQKxARuAjluywS1SatFuy
> token_duration          767h59m35s
> token_renewable         true
> token_policies          ["default" "sqlconnection"]
> identity_policies       []
> policies                ["default" "sqlconnection"]
> token_meta_role_name    sqlconnectionrole
> 
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> vault kv get devkv/connection
> ===== Data =====
> Key        Value
> source     DATA
> timeout    120

>
```

Comment: Version: Vault v1.4.1
And Nuget Package is
PackageReference Include="VaultSharp" Version="1.4.0.3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mountpoint is jumbled up with the key-path. Separate them out as follows:

```
var vaultSecrets = vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V1
   .ReadSecretAsync("connection", "devkv").Result.Data;
```